# Проблема с внесением данных в массив (C#)

Tags: c#, массивы

Пишу программу, которая должна получать от пользователя строку (цифры и пробелы), отделять цифры от пробелов и вносить это в отдельный массив (int[]).

Дело в том, что при внесении данных в новый массив, туда залетают непонятные мне цифры (не те, которые указывает пользователь).

Просьба пояснить, почему происходит именно так, и каким образом это можно пофиксить.

Вывод:

Введите строку с цифрами, разделенную пробелами: 1 2

49
0

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int number = 0;
        Console.Write("Введите строку с цифрами, разделенную пробелами: ");
        string str = Console.ReadLine();

        char[] array = str.ToCharArray();
        

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(array[i]) == " ")
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                number++;
            }
        }

        int[] array_int = new int[number];


        for (int i = 0; i < array_int.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(array[i]) == " ")
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                array_int[i] = Convert.ToInt32(array[i]);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array_int.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(array_int[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `int[] array_int = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(n => int.Parse(n)).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", array_int));` и в начале `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас в новый массив попадают коды символов - так работает `Convert.ToInt32()` с аргументом `Char`.

- Одно решение как это починить - вычесть код символа `0` из них (то есть отнять `Convert.ToInt32('0')`).
- Другой вариант - преобразовывать `array[i]` из `Char` в `String` и тогда `Convert.ToInt32()` с аргументом в виде строки отработает так как вы хотите.

[Документация на Convert.ToInt32](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.5)

Update: У вас ещё и с нумерацией во втором цикле проблемы. Там тоже надо учитывать, что вы пробелы пропускаете, я исправил:

```
    int[] array_int = new int[number];
    number = 0; // добавил

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (Convert.ToString(array[i]) == " ")
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            array_int[number] = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(array[i])); // исправил
            number++; // добавил
        }
    }
```

[Рабочий код, можно погонять, проверить](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vK7h4t)

Comment: array_int[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(array[i])); ?

Comment: Ну, например так. Попробуйте. Либо просто `Convert.ToInt32((string) array[i])` может тоже сработает

Comment: В этом случае всё равно получается странный вывод. При вводе 1 3 4, мы получаем выводом 1 0 3

Comment: Ну попробуйте отладочную печать понавтыкать и посмотреть, что у вас в array[i] например. Мне негде сейчас код проверить

Comment: И здесь смотрел, сразу в массив заносит эти "непонятные" цифры. Но всё равно спасибо большое за помощь.

Comment: @JeffreyWillis Я исправил, теперь правильно должно быть. У вас там индексация хромала. А цифры не непонятные, это коды символов.